# Android Bluetooth Discovery local devices can't found

Tags: java, android-studio, android-bluetooth

I was facing the issue that I tried to build an android applications that scan the nearby Bluetooth devices. In result I unable to find any devices nearby. I hereby attach my code kindly have look at it.

Thanks in Advance :)

```
private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
private Button onBtn, OffBtn, ListBtn, ScanBtn;
private TextView btStatus;
private BluetoothAdapter btAdapter;
private Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices;
private ListView btList;
private ArrayAdapter<String> btArrayAdapter;
private ArrayList<String> btArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
private int small = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
private int large = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if(btAdapter==null){
        onBtn.setEnabled(false);
        OffBtn.setEnabled(false);
        ListBtn.setEnabled(false);
        ScanBtn.setEnabled(false);
        btStatus.setText("Unsupported Device");
        bell("Device doesn't support Bluettoth",small);
    }else{
        btStatus = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.btStatus);
        onBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnOn);
        onBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                on(view);
            }
        });
        OffBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnOff);
        OffBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                off(view);
            }
        });

        ListBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btpaired);
        ListBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                paired(view);
            }
        });

        ScanBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btscan);
        ScanBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                scan(view);
            }
        });

        btList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.btlist);

        btArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,btArrayList);
        btList.setAdapter(btArrayAdapter);

    }
}
```

The below code are for enabling the Bluetooth adapter

```
public void on(View view){
    if(!btAdapter.isEnabled()){
        Intent onintent = new Intent(btAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(onintent,REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);

        bell("Bleutooth is turned on",small);

    }else{
        bell("Bluetooth is already turned on",small);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT){
        if(btAdapter.isEnabled()){
            btStatus.setText("Status : Enabled");
        }else{
            btStatus.setText("Status : Disabled");
        }
    }
}
```

The below code is for displaying the paired devices. It show the paired devices without isssue.

```
public void paired(View view){
    pairedDevices = btAdapter.getBondedDevices();

    for(BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices)
        btArrayAdapter.add(device.getName()+"\n"+device.getAddress());

    bell("Paired Devices",small);
}
```

I think I had done something wrong in here but I don't know what was wrong here :(

```
private final BroadcastReceiver btReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        bell("Debug 1",small);

        if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)){
            BluetoothDevice Device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            btArrayList.add(Device.getName()+"\n"+Device.getAddress());
            bell("Device Found"+Device.getName(),large);

        }
    }
};

public void scan(View view){
    if(btAdapter.isDiscovering()){
        btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    }else{
        btArrayAdapter.clear();
        btAdapter.startDiscovery();
        registerReceiver(btReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));
    }
}
```

The below code is for disabling the Bluetooth adapter

```
public void off(View view){
    btAdapter.disable();
    btStatus.setText("Status : Disconnected");

    bell("Bluetooth turned off",small);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(btReceiver);
}

public void bell(String str, int duration){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),str,duration).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was find the solutions for this issue. you just need to enable checkSelfPermission for the ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION. It will pop-up for the user to allow location permission. I guess that was the reason for not showing nearby devices.